# Run a PowerShell script in Task Scheduler that is located on network location

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, unc

I'm trying to administer PowerShell scripts on a central shared location. At the moment the .ps1 scripts are all stored on many different servers.

The scripts are used in Scheduled Tasks with the 'Action' specifics:

- Program/script: powershell.exe
- Add arguments (optional): G:..\scriptABC.ps1
- Start in (optional): C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Now the goal is to have them all on a shared location:

- \\domain\root..\scripts\scriptABC.ps1

**Problem:**
When I update the 'Add arguments' field to "\\domain\root..\scripts\scriptABC.ps1" and try to start the task, it'll say Running for a few seconds and than Ready again, but nothing happened. So it works like a charm when a local drive is specified, but not when a UNC path is specified.

Additional info:

- Working on Windows Server 2012 R2

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your argument \\domain\root..\scripts\scriptABC.ps1, or -file \\domain\root..\scripts\scriptABC.ps1? The -file is required for a shortcut or to launch a PS1 via BAT/VBS, so I would assume it's the same in a scheduled task.

Comment: Adding the **-File** worked for me. Strange that it isn't required for local scripts, but it is required for scripts located via an UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

Also the machine running the task will need to have permission to access the file on the network

Comment: Specifying the -Path didn't work. For the solution, see my comment on the above comment from Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have set your [Execution Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.3) to allow running scripts:

- Program: `powershell.exe`
- Arguments: `-File "\\unc\path\file.ps1"`